# Very different execution times for Update on different MySQL systems

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, subquery, database-performance

I have a very strange situation with MySQL.

Take the following example:
A table containing 15000 entries

```
CREATE TABLE `temp_geonis_export` (
`auto_id` INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
`obj_id` VARCHAR(10),
`gis_id` VARCHAR(45),
`letzteReinigung_id` VARCHAR(10),
INDEX `Index_2`(`gis_id`),
PRIMARY KEY (`auto_id`)
)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Now I'm updating 14000 of the rows in the table. I know, its a pretty ugly statement that could easily be rewritten, but that is not the question...

```
Update temp_geonis_export as temp
inner join (
Select gis_id, obj_id from 
(
Select abw.gis_id, abw.bezeichnung, erh.obj_id
from od_abwasserbauwerk as abw
inner join od_erhaltungsereignis as erh on erh.fs_abwasserbauwerk = abw.obj_id and erh.status = 2
inner join od_reinigung as unter on unter.obj_id = erh.obj_id
order by fs_abwasserbauwerk asc, erh.zeitpunkt asc
) as alleSortiert group by alleSortiert.gis_id
) as naechsteRein on temp.gis_id = naechsteRein.gis_id
set temp.naechsteReinigung_id = naechsteRein.obj_id;
```

Now, if I run the Update-statement on our development server, it takes about 1 sec. On one of our production servers it takes 90 seconds!!

These are my observations:

- Handler_read_rnd_next 101000 (development), 266177000 (production)
- Very high CPU Usage on production system (due to the above observation)
- Almost no Disk IO on both Systems
- When I rewrite the Update-Query and store the output of the subquery into a temporary table, the Update-Statement is fast on both systems

Due to the observations my conclusion is, that for some reason, our production server has to perform full table scans for each updated row. The development server does not. It must be a configuration issue, since our Servers are all 5.1.25 and the hardware is comparable.

Do you have a clue, what I have to change on our production server to make it perform better?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Post `EXPLAIN`s for your query both from developer and production servers

Comment: peterm, AFAIK, EXPLAIN Update is only available since MySQL 5.6. I can only use it for the subquery. The Subquery (Select) performs well on both systems.

Comment: Change `UPDATE`to `SELECT` to make the join that is used in update, ditch `SET` clause and do explain on the query in both environments and post it.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! For an unknown reason I can't upload Images to my Question, so I've uploaded them here: Development: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36580276/EDV/development.png) Production: [link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/36580276/EDV/production.png)

Comment: You'd better exec `EXPLAIN` in mysql (in command line) and post text output. It would be much more readable. Now as you can see you don't have all necessary indices in production environment.

Comment: peterm, thank you for your hint. next time I'll post the text output from the command line. I understand, that the query does not have the indexes, but why? I have tried to create the index with ALTER TABLE instead of creating it in CREATE TABLE, but this does not change the problem. I have also dumped the production DB to development (both Schema and Data). Again, on the development environment the index is used

Comment: Exec `DESC tablename` and `SHOW INDEX FROM tablename` for all your tables that are used in your query in both environments and compare them. My guess you are missing something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours I finally got the solution: 
The problem was, that the **DEFAULT CHARSET** on the production Server was different from the charset used in the database. Now, when creating the table **without explicitly specifying the charset**, MySQL did not use indexes. This is because MySQL can't use indexes on CHAR-Fields when the charsets of the joined tables differ.

Thank you so much for your help peterm. You pointed me into the right direction.